# How to convert String data into byte array using YAML library?

Tags: java, yaml

What I want to have is YAML configuration file, where I would be able to write pre-loaded data for database.

I'd like to have such config:

```
- books
  - !org.test.Book
    - name: TestName 
    - description: TestDescription
    - isbn: 960-425-059-0
```

Moreover, I would like to have a possibility to convert *isbn String field into the byte array field*

of Book class(or any other data type).

```
  class Book{
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private byte[] isbn;
  }
```

Is there any suitable YAML library for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Yaml libraries:

[JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/index.html)

[Yamlbeans](http://yamlbeans.sourceforge.net/)

You can still convert your byte array to String with a special encoding (that you should know). The way to convert it to a String is:

```
String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");  // example for one encoding type
```